# How to reduce the git output when checking out a tag

Tags: git

When I checkout a tag I get this output:

```
λ git checkout REL-6.2.0
Note: checking out 'REL-6.2.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at c154795... Set REL-6.2.0 in pom.xml on release/6.2.0 branch.
```

Is there a way to make the output a bit less or without the `git checkout` -b proposal? I know I can use something like `> /dev/null` but I would like some output but just less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for `git checkout`, you can use the `--quiet` flag to suppress certain types of output:

```
git checkout --quiet    # or just -q
```

I just checked out a prior commit on a local branch in the detached head state using the `--quiet` flag and there was no output in the console from Git.  Instead, I just saw the new prompt:

```
/c/users/timbiegeleisen/documents/project ((9e51b34...))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim Biegeleisen's answer explains how to suppress the message for a single checkout.

If you want to suppress the message permanently, you can use the setting [`advice.detachedHead`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-detachedHead):

```
git config advice.detachedHead false
```

As usual, this will only affect the current repo. Add option `--global` to set it globally (for your local user account).

Comment: As a one-off, you can use `git -c advice.detachedHead=false clone ...`

Answer (score 1):

Note that, before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the delayed checkout code path (using [filter drivers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-filterltdrivergtclean)) in "[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f0d795428e28fbfe6e86be0779e3d2fbfbdc73b4/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> etc... were chatty even when `--quiet` and/or `--no-progress` options were given.

See [commit 7a132c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a132c628e57b9bceeb88832ea051395c0637b16) (26 Aug 2021) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f0d7954](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0d795428e28fbfe6e86be0779e3d2fbfbdc73b4), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a132c628e57b9bceeb88832ea051395c0637b16): make delayed checkout respect `--quiet` and `--no-progress`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> The 'Filtering contents...' progress report from delayed checkout is displayed even when checkout and clone are invoked with `--quiet` or `--no-progress`.
>
> Furthermore, it is displayed unconditionally, without first checking whether stdout is a tty.
> Let's fix these issues.

---

The code to show progress indicator in a few code paths did not cover between 0-100%, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit bf6d819](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf6d819bc1589a41fbd4c8d9f55f0a6ebd6ef86f), [commit 4011224](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4011224944bf5dc6f38bce55edd5b4092ac0c930) (09 Sep 2021) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit df0c308](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df0c308c1a165e277ef3a7b8ae1457b926936d99), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`entry`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf6d819bc1589a41fbd4c8d9f55f0a6ebd6ef86f): show finer-grained counter in "Filtering content" progress line
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Let's also initialize the *progress to "`NULL`" while we're at it.
> Since [7a132c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a132c628e57b9bceeb88832ea051395c0637b16) ("`checkout`: make delayed checkout respect `--quiet` and `--no-progress`", 2021-08-26, Git v2.34.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0d795428e28fbfe6e86be0779e3d2fbfbdc73b4) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8463beaeb69fe0b7f651065813def4aa6827cd5d)) we have had progress conditional on `"show_progress",` usually we use the idiom of a "`NULL`" initialization of the "*progress", rather than the more verbose ternary added in [7a132c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a132c628e57b9bceeb88832ea051395c0637b16).